# Cloudinary, Carrierwave - setting resource_type to raw

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, carrierwave, cloudinary

I have Cloudinary and CarrierWave setted on Heroku hosting.
I need to upload SVG, and i was told to set "resource_type" to "raw"
[Cloudinary DOCS](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#raw_uploads)

I tried setting it in my carrierwave uploader:

```
process :resource_type
def resource_type
  return :resource_type => "raw"
end
```

And it didn't work. Can You help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method resource_type is used internally by the [Cloudinary CarrierWave code](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave.rb#L179) and overriding it like this will break the code.
If you need to override the resource_type to raw you can use:

```
cloudinary_transformation :resource_type=>:raw
```

However, this is usually not necessary as Cloudinary detects image vs. raw correctly.

Comment: I used `Cloudinary::Api.resources(:resource_type => :raw)` and it worked. I don't know what was the problem, maybe Heroku <-> Cloudinary? Same thing happend with png. I had to specify `process :convert => 'png'`. Thanks it worked.